# Folder/File smart link enable/disable call in Box V2 API

Tags: box-api

Recently an article on the box dev blog talked about an update in the V2 API functionality. http://developers.blog.box.com/2012/07/13/more-v2-updates/.

I am specifically talking about the share link for file/folders. The article says the API can be used to create/delete share links and also change the permission.But i do not see any such API on the http://developers.box.com/docs page.

Does anybody have any idea about this discrepancy? Is this available now in V2 or not?

Answer (score 1):

Smart links are treated as an attribute of a folder or file and can be created by updating the metadata about the folder or file. This is done through the PUT method. You can see this [here for files](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-update-a-files-information) and [here for folders](http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-update-information-about-a-folder).

For example, if you wanted to enable a shared link for a file you would make this call using cURL:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/FILE_ID \
-H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN" \
-d {"shared_link": {"access": "open"}} \
-X PUT
```

Comment: So updating method can be used to remove the link or change the permissions if the sharing is already enabled. However enabling/creating a link is still not possible since we cannot construct the uris ourselves. Any word on that issue?

Comment: You might be misunderstanding the documentation. I updated my answer above with an example.