# How to Create Shared Link of file in box api

Tags: android, box-api

I am integrating [box-api](http://developers.box.com/docs/) in my android application, i can successfully get file from FilePickerActivity in box android api. Now issue is that i don't know/understand how to get shared link of File, One question i know on SO is [Folder/File smart link enable/disable call in Box V2 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684640/folder-file-smart-link-enable-disable-call-in-box-v2-api) and [doc](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-create-a-shared-link-for-a-file) but ts generic how to do this in android.

Any suggestions are highly appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
BoxSharedLinkRequestObject slo = BoxSharedLinkRequestObject.createSharedLinkRequestObject(BoxSharedLinkAccess.OPEN);
BoxFileRequestObject bfro = BoxFileRequestObject.createSharedLinkRequestObject(slo);
boxClient.getFilesManager().createSharedLink(fileId, bfro);
```

Dont forget, you need to do it NOT in UI thread.